# Upload documents to sharepoint site using csv file

Tags: sharepoint, csv, upload

I have a list of filenames in a csv file.  Is there a way for sharepoint designer 2007 to parse those filenames and upload them from a directory into a document library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a PowerShell script:

- reading a CSV file is very simple ([Import-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) cmdlet)
- document library can be accessed using WebDav integration in Windows Explorer
- file operations are simple ([Copy-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx) cmdlet)